# Client-Server File Transfer in Java

Tags: java, file-io, tcp

I'm looking for an efficient way to transfer files between client and server processes using TCP in Java. My server code looks something like this:

```
socket = serverSocket.accept();
InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(filename));
```

I'm just unsure of how to proceed. I know I want to read bytes from `fis` and then write them to `os`, but I'm unsure about the best way to read and write bytes using byte streams in Java. I'm only familiar with writing/reading text using Writers and Readers. Can anyone tell me the appropriate way to do this? What should I wrap `os` and `fis` in (if anything) and how do I keep reading bytes until the end of file without a `hasNext()` method (or equivalent)

Comment: FTP library? SSH file transfer library (JSch)? No?

Comment: I have no experience with FTP, but if you could recommend a good Java FTP library then I'll definitely have a look.

Comment: For FTP server part, you can use Apache MINA FTP server library [http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/embedding-ftpserver-in-5-minutes.html](http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/embedding-ftpserver-in-5-minutes.html)

Comment: For FTP client part and other networking service library from Apache [http://commons.apache.org/net/](http://commons.apache.org/net/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
byte[] contents = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
int numBytes =0;
while((numBytes = is.read(contents))>0){
   os.write(contents,0,numBytes);
}
```

Comment: I have seen SO posts suggesting direct client-server file transfer via serializable objects approach like OP's code snippet above: is it reliable for large files with high network latency?

Comment: @eee The code in this post is all you need. Serializing entire files isn't a good idea: it just adds space and time costs to the above.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Very simple, just hadn't enough experience with BufferedStreams to know how to do it myself

Answer (score 2):

You could use Apache's IOUtils.copy(in, out) or

```
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams;
...
Streams.copy(in, out, false);
```

Inspecting the source might prove interesting. ( http://koders.com ?)

There is the java.nio.Channel with a transferTo method, with mixed opinions in the community wether better for smaller/larger files.

A simple block wise copy between Input/OutputStream would be okay. You could wrap it in buffered streams.